# MySQL Loop Through Queries / Digging Deeper

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a fairly complex database question to ask so I shall try and explain is as verbosely as possible.

I have one table called TypeAttributes.

typeID, attributeID, valueINT

From this table I wish to extract a certain type with a set of 6 attribute ID's.

So, I wish to end up with something like this from a query searching for typeID, in the below case typeID = 11446

```
typeID, attributeID, valueINT
11446   182          3000      
11446   183          3001      
11446   184          3002      
11446   277          5         
11446   278          2         
11446   279          2
```

From this information, I wish to then run the above query again, but with the valueINT of attributeID's 182, 183 and 184 as the typeID to query. So, then I should end up with a table look like this:

```
typeID, attributeID, valueINT
11446   182          3000     
11446   183          3001      
11446   184          3002      
11446   277          5         
11446   278          2         
11446   279          2         
3000    182          1000      
3000    183          1001
3000    277          5
3000    278          5
3001    182          51951
3001    277          3
3002    182          1000
3002    277          2
```

In the end, what I'm hoping to have is all of the prerequisite typeID's, 182 attribute values (which is actually a type of attribute im interested in),along side its secondary attribute (277).

From this data I should then be able to build a hierarchy of information simply from one item type. IE. I choose item type 11446, and it keeps going through the tree until there are no requisites.

Can this be done entirely in SQL to output a table like this?

I hope this makes some sense to someone.

Kind regards

PS.

As a side note, the attribute ID ties into another table which tells me which kind of attribute im looking at and the value is the value of that attribute, in this case, valueINT is actually another typeID I wish to lookup via the exact same process.

182, 183 and 184 are certain types and 277, 278 and 279 and multipliers of those types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to consider using a method called [modified preorder traversal](http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/) to store tree structured data - this method lets you easily find all nodes which a children of a given node to any depth in a single query.

It seems you have several trees each defined by a particular attribute. Each of these attributes would be replaced by a pair of values to store a left and right node identifier.